# Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Handling Issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have installed Visual studio 2010 Ultimate newly in my system for 64 bit. It is looking some what difference. I could not choose my class names and object names form the drop down menu. It [image]is hidden.

How to get that in **Visual Studio 2010**

Answer (score 1):

Enable it in Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages >

Check the 'navigation bar' checkbox.

[image]